# Android: Getting notified when applications load to foreground

Tags: android, android-broadcast, foreground

I have a background service on Android which needs to know which application is running in the foreground.
This will allow us to go very quiet when certain applications run, to avoid impacting their performance.  Over time we expect to build a list of applications to avoid.

I don't see any action being broadcast when an applications goes to the foreground, except within that application.

Am I missing something in the Android documentation?

Comment: There's no official API for this, it was possible to obtain window focus changed callbacks in `AccessibilityService`, but it was deemed an exploit by Google and it's actively purged / denied from the Play Store.